# Take text data from a photo by a user for verification use

Tags: android, ios, text, camera, verification

I'm looking for a library or a API (preferably java), Where I can use a sample picture of a form where users download this form, fill it up, and then take a picture of it using their smartphones, and then extract some data from it and use this data for whatever reason (verification, generating stuff, etc...) is it possible?

I saw once a video from canary delivery where in one part they use the ID in order to confirm your identity, how is that possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) is the reference (http://docs.opencv.org/java/). Do you looked on github if this idea is already shared ?